# Issues executing command line in some type of software but not others

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm having issues running a command line in some type of software, e.g. VSC, Rstudio, etc. but not in others, e.g. Terminal, Pycharm. For example:

#### In Terminal

```
katarzynakulma@Katarzynas-Air ~ % docker --version
Docker version 20.10.2, build 2291f61
katarzynakulma@Katarzynas-Air ~ % git --version
git version 2.30.0
```

#### In VSC

```
Katarzynas-Air:~ katarzynakulma$ docker --version
bash: docker: command not found
Katarzynas-Air:~ katarzynakulma$ git --version
bash: git: command not found
```

My OS is macOS Catalina 10.15.7

This was not always the case but I can't identify what triggered the change.
I'm not sure how to even start debugging it, so any hints are welcome

Comment: According to the prompt, you are using `zsh` in Terminal, but `bash` in VSC. `$PATH` seems to be correctly set for docker command in zsh, but not in bash.

Comment: well spotted, will follow this up